# how to duplicate row in table and update the IDs of the proceeding rows in a sproc?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the following table:
[image]

Im working on a procedure which takes in a row ID eg.5 and duplicates it into a new row with the ID of 6. by doing this I have to update the proceeding ids of item 6 to 7, 7 to 8, 8 to 9, 9 to 10 and 10 to 11.

what is the best way of doing this?

I am totally clueless in SQL manipulation so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Will you be passing the source row ID and supplying the new ID?

Comment: Or are you simply trying to update all IDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your IDs are always sequential, you'll want to `UPDATE` your table before doing the new `INSERT`:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET ID = ID + 1
WHERE ID >= 6
```

Then you can run your `INSERT` statement to duplicate row 5.

With that said, what is the purpose of this?  It might make more sense to rethink your table design.

*EDIT - If you need to do the insert as well*

If you also need to perform the `INSERT`, then this should work using `INSERT INTO`:

```
INSERT INTO YourTable 
SELECT 6, NextCol, NextCol, ...
FROM YourTable
WHERE ID = 5
```

Basically you have to supply each of the columns.  Again though, run this after you run the `UPDATE`.  If you have an Identity on this field, then this would not necessarily work.  Depends on your table structure.

Comment: This is simply updating the record, not inserting new as requesetd

Comment: @JasonCarter -- my understanding was OP wanted to update all records after the duplication -- easy enough to duplicate as well.  Still think we need addl clarification from OP.  I don't downvote people for giving valid syntax to help with a problem (especially if it were a misunderstanding of the issue -- even you asked in your comments if the OP just wanted to UPDATE)...

Comment: I agree, the request is unclear, and using either of the methods we are suggesting woudl cause havoc with any identity column, which would be another entire conversation.

Answer (score 0):

Question is bit unclear whether you looking for an insert or update. For an insert you could do something like below using a `cross join`:

[Sql-Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/03176/7)

```
insert into YourTable (ID, SupplierId, Title,...)
select MyID, SupplierId, Title, ...
from YourTable cross join (values (6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11)) 
          AS temp(MyId)
where YourTable.ID = 5
```

If ID is an auto incremented field then remove ID and MyID from the field list.